# what is the largest known prime number that does NOT have an efficient primality test

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

What is the largest known prime number that does NOT have a special form or special primality test (like mersenne, fermat, SB,...) ?
And how was it found ?

Comment: What does 'SB' mean please?

Comment: it stands for seventeen or bust which aims to find Sierpinski primes https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeen_or_Bust

Comment: Thank you for interesting link! Following by this link, one can find document http://primes.utm.edu/primes/lists/all.pdf, where page 121 has topic "2. The Long Primes". Here primes with rank 222,1159, 1785, ... have much more complicated form (testing applications: OpenPFGW, FastECPP).

Comment: *The World Has A New Largest-Known Prime Number*, There's a new behemoth in the ongoing search for ever-larger prime numbers — and it's nearly 25 million digits long. https://www.npr.org/2018/12/21/679207604/the-world-has-a-new-largest-known-prime-number?utm_campaign=storyshare&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_medium=social&fbclid=IwAR3JPtG_toEtR1XiZsZU_OvEOkD2vH17uGZmDTPM1PughJLSMsVRnZr4uec

Comment: @user601647  What do you mean with a "special form" ?